# How To Tell If a CPU Supports Virtualization

Tags: virtualization

I know if you are in front of the computer there are easy ways to determine if virtualization is supported. I want to know if the CPU supports virtualization before I buy it.

What do CPU's need to have built in to support virtualization and how do I tell if a CPU does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) a list of Intel processors which support virtualization; [here's](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/GPU120AMDRVICPUsHyperVWin8.aspx) the same for AMD. (The AMD list specifically mentions Hyper-V, which is a Microsoft technology, but judging by [this page from the Linux KVM site](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support), the underpinnings are the same regardless of which hypervisor you're using.)

Comment: Just remember, it's not only the processor but the motherboard also has to support this. In some cases, vendors such as HP will ship a CPU and Motherboard that supports these features but they are not exposed in the BIOS and have it disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link http://www.technorms.com/8208/check-if-processor-supports-virtualization that list three ways to Check If Your Processor Supports Virtualization. You can follow the steps and the illustrated pictures to check if your CPU supports visualization.

Here is a link http://www.everythingvm.com/content/picking-motherboard-and-processor-use-virtualization that talks about what to look for and consider when looking for a CPU that supports vitalization.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Downvoted for inapplicability; the question says "I want to know if the CPU supports virtualization before I buy it", and all of the methods described in your link require that you be running a machine with the CPU in question in it.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to wonder whether the motherboard would also need to support virtualization, something which your second link addresses; I've removed the downvote. (But note Oliver Salzburg's comment regarding links vs. inclusion of apposite info. Generally on a Stack Exchange site, when you receive advice from someone whose name has the moderator's diamond after it, that advice is worth following.)

Comment: @Aaron, your suggested is strongly noted. I am in the process of fully understanding all the pertinent rules on Stack Exchange site. Thanks for the suggestion and observation.